# Why await stops executing the thread and the result is awaiting activation in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I have an `async` method as here below:

```
protected async Task<string> DoSomeStuff()
{
    dynamic info = await fb.GetTaskAsync("me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,link,locale,email,name,birthday,gender,location,age_range,about".GraphAPICall(appsecret_proof));
    //this breaks the thread?
    string result = "result123";
    return result;
    //result is always null
}
```

The `await` breaks the thread and results into an infinite loop. I can't access the value of result as it is awaiting activation. What am I missing here?

Comment: Is it really an infinite loop (as in: gets called again and again) or a deadlock (A is waiting for B to finish, which is blocked by A, caused by a mix of sync and async code)

Comment: I just have only one task in my method and you can have a look at edited question

Comment: Await does *not* stop execution. It *releases* the thread while *awaiting* for an asynchronous operation to complete

Comment: @HansKesting none of those which you mentioned. I call for this method from a controller action and expecting a string to be returned the call goes for the method and does execute the method until above api call hit then it returns back to the controller and the result is null

Comment: Show the code for your controller action, then. Is it async?

Comment: your async call may be unable to finish due to connection problems or other errors.

Comment: @Newbie the key point is that `DoSomeStuff` *doesn't return a `string`*... it returns a `Task<string>` - essentially a *promise* of a string at some future point. You need to `await` that promise (which might be already available, might not be). Once you start `async`, it is `await` ***all the way down***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your controller method should be marked as async and you should await on DoSomeStuff().

E.g.

```
    public async ActionResult YourControllerAction()
    {
        var result = await DoSomeStuff();
    }
```

Comment: Whatta great answer! I really love straight forward answers and yours is just another one.

Answer (score 0):

The *purpose* of `await` is to apply the rest of the code *as a continuation* if the thing being awaited has not completed. The fact that it suspended execution tells us that the result of `dostuff` has indeed: not already completed.

The interesting question is: *will it ever complete?* (either successfully or as an exception is fine). Only you can tell us that. It is possible that `dostuff` returns something that is never going to complete; for example, you could create a `TaskCompletionSource<T>` and hand back the `.Task` without ever actually doing anything that would call `SetResult` at some future time. What is `dostuff`?

Comment: `dostuff` is an API call to facebook graph and the result should be a json. I'll edit the question with right await call so you can have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

> The await breaks the thread and results into an infinite loop.

An "await" is an "asynchronous wait". In other words, the method is paused but the thread continues executing.

> I can't access the value of result as it is awaiting activation.

"Waiting for activation" is the (unfortunately confusing) status for asynchronous tasks that *are in progress*. I have a [blog post on task statuses](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/a-tour-of-task-part-3-status.html) - in this case, it's a Promise Task, and `WaitingForActivation` is exactly what you *should* see if the task has started but has not yet completed.

Since it seems that your task *never* completes, I would suspect a deadlock. [Deadlocks are easily caused by blocking (e.g., `Result`/`Wait`) further up your call stack](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).